# iPhone: Safari password manager does not work with Hotmail anymore

Tags: iphone, safari, password, login, hotmail

Having a Microsoft Hotmail account I used to login on my iPhone Safari browser using the Safari password manager.

But since Microsoft changed the login screen to a two step procedure (first the username and the password on the next screen, aka "progressive login procedure"), the password manager cannot fill in the login name and the password anymore.

How do I use the Safari password manager on iPhone to manage my password for Hotmail login (http://login.live.com) again?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this? I'm having the same problem with Safari on macOS as well. Highly annoying.

Comment: no, still doesn't work. annoying, indeed!